# WSO2 API Management - Docker Compose - Login error after installation using default parameters

Tags: docker, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I can't login to WSO2 API Manager after installation.

I perform the installation as indicated in these steps: https://wso2.com/api-management/install/docker-compose/get-started/
API Manager for Docker Compose.

According to the instructions:

> Running the product: Once WSO2 API Manager is successfully deployed,
> access the following URLs on your favorite web browser using the
> credentials username: admin and password: admin.

Try to login in   **https://localhost:9443/carbon/admin/login.jsp**

I try, using user: admin password: admin, but I have this error message in the log:

**api-manager_1 | [2021-02-20 03:19:36,643] ERROR - AuthenticationAdmin System error while Authenticating/Authorizing User : java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.**

What am I doing wrong? thanks in advance.

Comment: Were you able to access publisher and devportal? Looks like connection is not there for the MySQL container. Maybe container is down

Comment: Hi, solved, thanks, I finally deleted all installation and did it clean again and there if the connection worked. I didn't reproduce error exactly, but it seemed to be doing something wrong with MySQL up in Docker..